# WxPython StaticBitmap not clearing

Tags: python-3.x

- I want to load a StaticBitmap in a Scrolledcanvas
- First time is OK.
- Then I want to upload another one in place of the existing one.
- But I do not manage to clear the ScrolledCanvas :

  - both image appears

```
class FAI(wx.Frame):
 .... init stuff ....

        self.viewer = wx.ScrolledCanvas(self)
        self.viewer.SetScrollbars(1, 1, 500, 500)
        self.CreateStatusBar()

        self.inside_view = wx.BoxSizer()
        self.viewer.SetSizer(self.inside_view)

    def im_load(self, event):  # wxGlade: MyFrame.<event_handler>
        dlg = wx.FileDialog(None)
        if dlg.ShowModal() == wx.ID_OK:
            path = dlg.GetPath()
            print("%s" % dlg.GetPath())
        image = wx.StaticBitmap(
            self.viewer, wx.ID_ANY, wx.Bitmap(path, wx.BITMAP_TYPE_ANY)
        )
        self.inside_view.Add(image)
        self.Refresh()
        dlg.Destroy()

class MyApp(wx.App):
......
```

Answer (score 0):

Answer from my side :
fixed using

```
        self.inside_view.Clear(delete_windows=True)
        self.inside_view.Add(image)
```

delete_windows must be True